# How to Sumproduct with SUMIFS from another sheet without making extra columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to get the SUMPRODUCT (total specific cost) for projects (with employees' code and employees' cost, projects' code from a sheet and a sheet of working hours in month with employees' code, projects' code and working hours).
I dont want to make extra columns because there are so many many employees'code then it will to too big to view all. I've researched but not sucessed at all.

It looks like this:

Sheet 1: [image: Result sheet]

And the data in Sheet 2:
[image: Data]

I've made a simple example for the request, could you guys help me to suggest nice formulas. I'm using Excel 2013.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FM-YhoL7D5ZSmjGN2lSMm7xaVUS1vjILOhRqQSKNQLs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post the essential portions here so that we don't have to click on links.

Comment: @RohitGupta It's hard to explain details so I made a demonstration in GGsheets link

Comment: Why do you want to use Sumifs()?? If you want to SumProduct, why don't you  use SumProduct()???

Comment: @teylyn I don't know exactly which formula is the best for my case. Normally, I'm able to use SUMPRODUCTS from many SUMIFS columns, but I don't want to make extra columns (from SUMIFS) in this case then I try a way to combine SUMPRODUCT and SUMIFS

Comment: please edit your question and explain the logic of what you want to calculate. It's not quite apparent which data flows into the total in cell G11, G12, etc. and why. You may want to consider using PowerPivot, which can do calculations across different tables without generating more columns in the grid. If you want to stick with worksheet formulas, sometimes you will need helper columns to arrive at the desired output.

Comment: Did the Costs Worksheet is the value for 1 hour?